# Memory cache with sql cache dependency

Tags: caching, .net-core, sqlcachedependency

I'm trying to cache data like application resources which already stored in database.

How do I implement memory cache with SQL cache dependency in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports SQL Dependency, you can use it to remove or add the item back to the cache. When `OnChange` is invoked, either remove the item from the cache or insert the item again.

```cs
public class CacheWithDbDependency {
    IMemoryCache _cache;
    public CacheWithDbDependency(IMemoryCache cache) {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    private void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) {
        // Here remove or reinsert your item with latest data
    }
    public AddWithDbDependency(string Key, object value) {
        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(com);
        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
        _cache.SetValue(your data);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you have to query the data and determine change after some interval and invalidate the data.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core supports several different caches. The simplest cache is based on the `IMemoryCache`.

you can use the bellow code to caches.

I have interface `ICacheManagement`

```
public interface ICacheManagement
{
    T GetValue<T>(object key, T defaultValue = default(T));
    void SetValue<T>(object key, T value, int timeoutInSeconds);
    void SetSlidingValue<T>(object key, T value, int timeoutInSeconds);
    void Remove(object key);
    void Remove(List<object> keys);
    void ClearTableCache(string tableName);
    void ClearTableCache(List<string> tableName);
    void ClearAllCaches();

}
```

class `CacheManagement`

```
public class CacheManagement : ICacheManagement
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    public CacheManagement(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    public T GetValue<T>(object key, T defaultValue = default) 
        => _memoryCache.TryGetValue<T>(key, out var cacheValue) ? cacheValue : defaultValue;

    public void SetValue<T>(object key, T value, int timeoutInSeconds) =>
        _memoryCache.Set<T>(key, value, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)));

    public void SetSlidingValue<T>(object key, T value, int timeoutInSeconds) =>
        _memoryCache.Set<T>(key, value, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)));

    public void Remove(object key) => _memoryCache.Remove(key);

    public void Remove(List<object> keys) => keys.ForEach(Remove);

}
```

Use cache, I assume you have a Customer class and a repository for it

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private readonly ICacheManagement _cacheManagement;

    public CustomerRepository(ICacheManagement cacheManagement)
    {
        _cacheManagement = cacheManagement;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllSetting()
    {
        string cacheKey = $"cacheKey";

        IEnumerable<Customer> listSetting = _cacheManagement.GetValue<IEnumerable<Customer>>(cacheKey, null);
        if (listSetting != null)
            return listSetting;

        IEnumerable<Customer> setting = ...; //get data from database

        int temporaryCacheExpireInSeconds = 20;//time cache for this cacheKey
        _cacheManagement.SetValue<IEnumerable<Customer>>(cacheKey, setting, temporaryCacheExpireInSeconds);

        return setting;
    }
}
```